# WPF Webbrowser Control proxy'ing external URL's

Tags: c#, wpf, browser

The webrowser control has a navigating event that is raised before the browser navigates to a URL, but what I need is a preview event for when the webbrowser requests referenced media/pages/css. For example when a image tag is seen by the control, it will request the image from its URL.  I need to proxy this URL to decide if I should display it, deny it, or change it.

Is this even possible using the control?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps having a second, hidden browser that can load the next page and collect information (such as image information) would be your best bet.

Comment: ... Download the URL and decode it looking for all the Links/References?

Comment: I think this is what we were doing currently, the problem is looking for links in all pages is sort of unstandardized and browsers have powerful code thats already doing this. So what I want to do is black box the browser and mediate trafic to and from.